# Custom URLConnectionDataDelegate

Tags: ios, delegates, nsurlconnection

I'm stuck whilst trying to create a custom *URLConnectionDataDelegate* for my *NSURLConnection* requests. The problem is that I can create a class that implements the delegate protocol and make a request doing:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:myDelegate];
```

But then in the delegate functions, like `(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`, I have to modify some UI elements and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Where do your UI elements sit? Please provide more detail. Using NSNotificationCenter may be a good route to keep your code decoupled.

Comment: @Cirrostratus The UI elements sits in the View associated with the Controller that makes the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dedicated class (not a UIViewController class) that implements the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol, you should not modify the UI elements in your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method. This method is for "internal" use of your "connection" class.

What you need is a way to obtain the eventual result of the request from your "connection" object. That is, the response data or - possibly - an error.

One way to achieve this is to provide a property in your "connection" class that takes a *completion block* and this block will be called by your class when the connection finished.

`typedef void (^completion_block_t)(id result);`

`@property (nonatomic, copy) completion_block_t completionHandler;`

Then, whenever your connection finished (for whatever reason) you call the block with the result which is either the response data (possibly a `NSMutableData` which contains the accumulated data chunks) or an `NSError` object which you got from the connection or created yourself - for example when you didn't get the correct Content-Type or when the connection actually finished but the status code doesn't mean a successful request in your apps logic.

An example how you would use it in your View Controller:

```
// somewhere in your UIViewController:    
MyConnection* con = [[MyConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request];
__weak MyViewController* weakSelf = self;  // idiom to avoid circular references
con.completionHandler = ^(id result){
    if (![result isKindOfClass:[NSError error]]) {
        // do something with the response data:
        NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result 
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // UIKit methods:
            weakSelf.myLabel.text = string;
        });
    }
    else {
        // Error
    }
};

// Start the connection:
[con start];
```

Comment: This seems like the answer I was looking for! A completion block! Thank you very much, I'll try to implement it in my App. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either make your view controller the delegate and modify UI element in the callbacks, or have the custom delegate object message the view controller when updates happened. The latter can be done using KVO/binding, notifications, delegation, blocks or another way.